# Storing data from input pins

Tags: input-device, analog-to-digital

I have a RPi and attached to an input pin I have an ADC (MCP3002) and an op-amp (MCP601) and a piezo element connected to them. 
The RPi reads the input pin, gets the digital data and at the moment generates a graph using Matplotlib.

I want to take this data and store it in a meaningful way so I can analyse the input from the piezo and determine the frequency of the vibration.
I understand I may need to use a codec (not sure how to develop using this) and to get the data I plan on using FFT algorithm to establish the frequencies present.
The code I have used is an adaptation of the code found [here](http://www.raspberrypi-spy.co.uk/2013/10/analogue-sensors-on-the-raspberry-pi-using-an-mcp3008/)

The voltage generated is digitized and converted to it's digital number equivalent and plotted on a graph to generate a waveform graph. I just want to convert it to a WAV file or something that can be analysed effectively using FFT.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using matplotlib, then you are using Python, correct?  If so, then for FFTs, you'll likely want to look at scipy or numpy.

For generating WAV files, Python includes a library called wave that can generate wave files from raw samples.

Comment: I've also been on a raspberry pi forum and it's been suggested that I could use CSV format and find a FFT algorithm to analyse raw values

Comment: If your values were in CSV format, you could read the values into Python (csvreader is  a Python library), and then use numpy or scipy to do the FFTs.  But there's certainly also many programs that can just read in and display an FFT from a CSV (it's even something you could do in Excel (I think with a plugin)).